# See if user has spent x minutes browsing SITE

Tags: jquery, cookies, local-storage, session-storage

Measuring how long a user has spent on a single page is no problem, but what is the preferred way of checking how long a user has spent browsing a site with multiple pages? I need to show the user a div after two minutes of browsing anywhere on the site.

All help most appreciated.

Comment: does the user has to login?

Comment: @Rudy No login required in this portion of the site.

Answer (score 2):

Just store a timestamp inside a cookie (or session) when the user first visit your site, than check the timestamp in some interval (or on page load) and when its older than 2 min fire some event. You can do this both client and server side.